# Issue with C++ Vector implementation

Tags: c++, vector, iterator

So I have an interesting issue with some code that I copied from my text book for notes. I like to type out these little example programs and run them to help myself understand them. With that said, I actually typed this program out word for word but I am getting an error after hitting compile and run. I am not sure if it has to do with my IDE or not. Here is the program and below is the error. Thanks for any help in advance

```
//use of iterator, begin, and end
#include <iostream>

//include iterators
#include <iterator>

//include vectors for use
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

//the main function
int main() {
    vector<int> myVector = (10, 20, 30, 40, 50);

//declare iterator
vector<int>::iterator
myIterator;

cout << "My vector values are: ";

//use begin and end to print values to screen
for(myIterator = myVector.begin(); myIterator < 
myVector.end(); myIterator++) {
    cout << * myIterator << " " ;
} //end of for loop
return 0;
} //end main
```

Error is in line 14 as you can see from below. Again this program was typed out line per line from my textbook so I can study it but it does not work when I compile and run. I have also tried changing the () around the values in the vector to {} but I am still getting errors after doing that.

14  44  C:\Users\hulkg\OneDrive\Documents\C++ code examples\Iterator_begin_end.cpp  [Error] conversion from 'int' to non-scalar type 'std::vector' requested

Comment: You want `vector<int> myVector = {10, 20, 30, 40, 50};` to do list initialization: https://onlinegdb.com/SJv-c6BQu   (braces, not parenthesis)

Comment: You have parenthesis when initializing `myVector`.  You want curly braces (`{}`).  And make sure you're building with C++11 or later.

Comment: Read about the operator comma and you will get meaning of the error message.

Comment: Thanks for the responses guys. I have actually tried changing it to braces {} and i get the following error.

Comment: 14 44 C:\Users\hulkg\OneDrive\Documents\C++ code examples\Iterator_begin_end.cpp [Error] in C++98 'myVector' must be initialized by constructor, not by '{...}'

Comment: As already have been pointed out, you have to use C++11 or later. Unfortunately, while basically all compilers do support C++11 (and later,) some don't enable the support by default (and in fact, your compiler is telling you so; in the "C++98" stuff in the error message.) You should check around to see how you can enable C++11 in your development environment.

Comment: Ah okay, I figured since 98 was higher than 11 lol I suppose that must be more along the lines of like windows 98 vs windows 10.

Comment: :)) I guess I should have explained that these are *years*, and 11 is in fact 2011, vs 98 which is 1998.

Comment: Perfect got a newer version of my IDE and it is working how it should. Thank you all for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My IDE was outdated as stated by @yzt and @Stephen Newell. After updated to a newer version the code is performing as expected. Furthermore, the () needed to go back to their original {} as stated by @Jerry Jeremiah and @Stephen Newell. My understanding of the outdated IDE is a direct contribution from @yzt's comment. Thank you all.